# How should we format glosses on linguistics.SE?

Tags: discussion

What will be our best choice of formatting for including glosses of foreign language samples in our questions?

Comment: Did you mean linguistics.SE?

Comment: Yes! I was brainwashed by the broken logo as I typed apparently (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually writes the translation under the quotation, between quotes, and the gloss between them, in roman, as in

> *Gwenn eo ar c'haz*
>   White is the cat
>   “The cat is white”

Slashes and dashes may be used for compound words

> *Bayerische Seenschifffahrt*
>   Bavarian / lakes-shipping
>   “Bavarian lakes shipping”<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. This is probably not the best example I could come with, but the triple *f* made me do it anyway :).</sup>

Comment: Is there anything we could do as the samples get longer to keep the glosses in line horizontally? Perhaps we could force a monospaced font?

Comment: @hippietrail: It would solve the alignment issue, but I don't like the look of `code blocks`. Perhaps a `<pre>` block would fit better.

Comment: Yes how do we do a pre in markdown?

Comment: @hippietrail: See edit's help popup *?* -> HTML or [this question on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked about [rendering glosses in HTML](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-do-i-format-an-interlinear-gloss-for-html) on linguistics.SE, so there's some worthwhile discussion going on there.

Naturally, I'm biased toward my own suggestion. :) But in all seriousness, the approach I describe there does have the advantage of being encode-able with markup that the SE software already supports (embedded lists). However, in order to get it to render in such a way that it looks like a gloss, there would have to be a way for this particular site (linguistics.SE) to edit its CSS file, and then, I suppose, secondarily, some way to tell Markdown that the `<ol>` (or whatever people ended up settling on, hypothetically) should have a class of `.gloss` or something like that.

I have no idea if both of those are possible, but I thought I'd throw out the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

A common glossing convention is the [Leipzig Glossing Rules](http://grammar.ucsd.edu/courses/lign120/leipziggloss.pdf).

Unfortunately it mandates horizontal alignments that are difficult to achieve in plain Markdown.

As a workaround, you can write the gloss as a code block (indent by 4 spaces), as in [The stylistic effect of chiasmus in Latin](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3100/1021):

> ```
> sidere         mens           eadem          mutato
> star-SG.N.ABL  mind-SG.F.NOM  same-SG.F.NOM  change-SG.N.ABL
> ```

But this prevents you from using formatting.